# Find object from another scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to find an object from another scene. I have checked both `Find` and `FindWithTag`, but both of them give me this error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: is your other scene loaded? I don't think you can easily reference objects from scenes that are not currently in ram

Comment: You can't. Loading a new scene removes all the objects from previous so it won't exist. If you need data from an object in previous scene, look into persistent data, like PlayerPrefs.

Comment: @Everts if you use additive scene loading, content of the previous one won't get purged

Comment: Thanks for all your answers and yes you are right its immposible to reference object from scene u havent loaded yet , I checked using additive scene loading but it displays both scenes at same time and i dont need it...  The situation is this : I have scene there i have button and when I click on it gameobject (it is  in another scene which i havent loaded yet ) should change its sprite.

Answer (score 0):

As i know - there is no way to find object on other scene. 
First idea - you can load it as additive scene using `SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherSceneName", LoadSceneMode.Additive);`
and then use `Find`

You may find more info here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer  I checked using additive scene loading but it displays both scenes at same time and i dont need it...  The situation is this : I have scene there i have button and when I click on it gameobject (it is  in another scene which i havent loaded yet ) should change its sprite.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Game Manager, which can make a script/object that will persist between different scenes, allowing you to carry variables between them.  You could use it to have the button change a variable, then have the other scene check the variable when it loads to change the sprite.

A Unity tutorial is here:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike-tutorial/writing-game-manager

Comment: I used to do this.  It is a solid approach.  However, I eventually decided that the dependency cost was just too high.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, I'd use PlayerPrefs.Save/SetString to save the variables when player interacts with your UIs or Game Objects in Scene A.
Then when you loading your Scene B, write a scene manager script and on its Awake(), use PlayerPrefs.GetString to retrieve variables, and change your game object behaviors based on the loaded variables.